# Xpath expression working in chrome console but returns empty in puppeteer

Tags: xpath, puppeteer

I have the following expression :

```
page.$x('//label[normalize-space()=\'Install\']/input[@aria-hidden=\'false\']')
```

It is returning the required array when I test in chrome browser console, but returns an empty array inside puppeteer.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Dynamic HTML content?

Comment: @Andersson Yes. Its an input field populated by an ajax call.

Comment: @Andersson thank you , fixed it by waiting for a class created by angular after ajax call response is received